# Can't install PHPmyadmin (package cannot be located)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and had done various changed in my system in the last day. I can't exactly show all these processes here but I do ask for an advice on this particular issue, to understand what's going on:

When executing:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
```

I didn't find any helpful solution on the Web.

---

### Update 1 - Update for Arduino Sentinel:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php but it is not installable
              Depends: php-mbstring
              Depends: libjs-sphinxdoc (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: dbconfig-mysql but it is not installable or
                       dbconfig-no-thanks but it is not installable or
                       dbconfig-common (< 2.0.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: php-php-gettext but it is not installable or
                       php-gettext (<= 1:7.0) but it is not installable
              Recommends: php-gd
              Recommends: php-bz2 but it is not installable
              Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Update 2 - Update for Arduino Sentinel:

> Package aptitude is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before installing `phpmyadmin`, you should be using a non-root user with sudo privileges, as described in [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04), also you should have a complete LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP) installation on. If you don't,then you can [Follow this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) on installing a LAMP stack on Ubuntu

If everything is okay,add this ppa

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

then install phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't help. I've updated the question with stdout.

Comment: i would suggest you use `aptitude` package manager as it will suggest easy solution to fix the unmet dependencies problem ,install via apt `sudo apt-get install aptitude` then install `phpmyadmin` `sudo aptitude install phpmyadmin` and choose a go solution suggest to fix your problem

Comment: It seems my system is broken becasue `apt-get install aptitude` can't be installed.

Comment: run this commands `sudo dpkg --configure -a` `sudo apt-get install -f` and try again

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: something fishy with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ,open it with gedit like `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`or `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list` then show me what its in there

Comment: `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51029/discussion-between-arduino-sentinel-and-benia).

Answer (score 1):

You require php, apache2, mysql-server installed

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php mysql-server
```

Then you need to add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
```

Then you need to update the package list:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then you can install:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```